# Failing to call method from ApplicationHelper module in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, controller, helper

I am struggling to call a method in one of my controllers.
When trying to I keep my controller skinny, I wanted to move some of the code to another place. I chose the ApplicationHelper, as the code is not clearly belonging to one of my models.

Here is my ApplicationHelper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def add_tag_to_vocab(vocab, tag)
    user = User.find(vocab.user_id)
    tag_handler = user.tags.where(name: tag).first  
    if tag_handler.nil? 
      tag_handler = user.tags.create(name: tag, active: true)
      vocab.tags << tag_handler
    else
      vocab.tags << tag_handler
    end
  end
end
```

Now I want to user this method in a controller. I try like this:

```
def import_vocabs
  ....
  add_tag_to_vocab(new_vocab, @wordsearch.keyword)
  ...
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render file: "wordsearches/wordsearch_finish.js.erb"}
  end
end
```

And I get this:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `add_tag_to_vocab' for #<WordsearchesController:0x007f86d18cec40>):
```

My questions are: 
How can I call this method from the ApplicationHelper and isn't it supposed to be automatically available? 
I tried to find the answer in the [Rails Guides Controller Page](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) but I didn't.

Depending on the answer:
Where would I put such a method, if the ApplicationHelper is not the right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include the module in the controller class from where you are trying to use it:

```
include ApplicationHelper
```

So, it should look like this:

```
class YourClassName
  include ApplicationHelper

  def import_vocabs
    add_tag_to_vocab(new_vocab, @wordsearch.keyword)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render file: "wordsearches/wordsearch_finish.js.erb"}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't they be automatically be included, or am I confusing something here? What's the big advantage of having them, i mean why does Rails create them for me if they are not having some logic included that makes them special over modules I would define myself?

Comment: Methods in ApplicationHelper are available in all views, but those methods will cause an error if called from the controller class. So, you need to `include ApplicationHelper` this in order to use the methods inside the controller.

Comment: Ok, then I confused views with controllers. If I may ask one more question: Where belongs such a function that is creating/associating objects in the db but needs to be available in more than one controller?

Comment: You can have a helper module for them, and include the module into the controller classes where the methods need to be available. But, again, it's a design perspective. There could be better ways of doing such thing.